# Contents of ui:repeat not updated with p:fileUpload

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I am running a JSF2 web application with PrimeFaces 3.5 on GlassFish 3.1.2. I want to implement CSV import functionality, so that the read values are filled in to the components without page reload.

Technically, after a file upload with [`<p:fileUpload>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/fileUploadSingle.jsf), I want to update a component which creates the input fields iteratively with `<ui:repeat>`. Here is the simplified code of my view:

```xml
<ui:define name="content">
    <h:form id="form" prependId="false" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" life="5000" />

        <p:panel header="Values">
            <h:panelGroup id="grid" layout="block">

                <p:commandButton actionListener="#{table.handlePost}"
                    id="postTop" value="Save" update="growl" />
                <p:commandButton id="dlTop" value="Export CSV" ajax="false"
                    onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(start, stop)"
                    icon="ui-icon-arrowthichk-s">
                    <p:fileDownload value="#{table.csv}" />
                </p:commandButton>

                <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{table.handleFileUpload}"
                    mode="advanced" update="tableView, growl" sizeLimit="10000"
                    allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(csv)$/" label="Import CSV"
                    showButtons="false" />

                <h:panelGroup id="tableView" layout="block">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Day</th>
                            <th>Value</th>
                        </tr>
                        <ui:repeat value="#{table.values}" varStatus="val" id="table">
                            <tr>
                                <td><h:outputText
                                        value="#{table.date}-#{val.index+1}" /></td>
                                <td><h:inputText id="value"
                                        value="#{table.values[val.index]}"
                                        converter="javax.faces.Double" /></td>
                            </tr>
                        </ui:repeat>
                    </table>
                </h:panelGroup>

                <p:commandButton actionListener="#{table.handlePost}"
                            id="postBottom" value="Save" update="growl" />
                <p:commandButton id="dlBottom" value="Export CSV" ajax="false"
                    onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(start, stop)"
                    icon="ui-icon-arrowthic hk-s">
                    <p:fileDownload value="#{table.csv}" />
                </p:commandButton>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </p:panel>

    </h:form>
</ui:define>
```

`table` bean:

```java
@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean(name="table")
public class TableView { }
```

Values are read correctly, I can update any component to output `table.values`, except with `<p:fileUpload>`, contents of the `<ui:repeat>` are never updated. If I update `tableView` from any other component other than `<p:fileUpload>`, the contents of `<ui:repeat>` are updated correctly. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the file upload component supports the ajax update tag, so you may have to do a full page refresh...you could do this in javascript by using: `oncomplete="javascript:window.location.reload(true)"`

Comment: The `update` attribute is listed in the official PrimeFaces documentation. In the example view I posted, the `growl` component gets updated successfully.

Comment: No, unfortunately this gives the same behaviour. I also tried to put `<p:fileUpload>` inside `<p:dialog><h:form></h:form></p:dialog>` and do `update=":form:tableView, :form:growl"`. But this also results the same thing.